# Trying to the sort the time in descending order

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I'm trying to sort the time exited cars in descending order. Example:

This's just a part of the data I'm using. The actual data includes more than 100 data.

I tried using .sort((a, b) => b - a) on, let outDate = new Date(car.out)(this probably didn't work because it was sorting the dates as well, not sure) , hoursOut.sort((a, b) => b - a) this didn't work either. Received not a function error

Thanks in advance!

```
function displayData(data) {

  data.forEach(car =>{
    // -------------------------------------------- Time in --------------
    let dateIn = new Date(car.in)
    let month = dateIn.getMonth()
    let date = dateIn.getDate();
    let fullYear = dateIn.getFullYear()
    let hoursIn = dateIn.getHours();
    let minutesIn = dateIn.getMinutes();
    let secondsIn = dateIn.getSeconds()

    let timeInFormat = hoursIn >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

    let timeIn = month + '/' + date  + '/' + fullYear + ' ' + hoursIn + ':' + minutesIn + ':' + secondsIn + " " + timeInFormat

//input: 1591855348009
//output: 5/11/2020 16:47:48 PM

//-------------------------------------------------- Time out --------------------------------------------
    // let x = car.out
    // let carsOut = x.sort((a, b) => b - a)
    let outDate = new Date(car.out);
    // let sortedList = outDate.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date)
    let monthOut = outDate.getMonth()
    let dateOut = outDate.getDate();
    let yearOut = outDate.getFullYear()
    let hoursOut = outDate.getHours();
    let minutesOut = outDate.getMinutes();
    let secondsOut = outDate.getSeconds()

    let timeOutFormat = hoursOut >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

    let timeOut = monthOut + '/' + dateOut  + '/' + yearOut + ' ' + hoursOut + ':' + minutesOut + ':' + secondsOut + " " + timeOutFormat


// ------------------------------------------ Duration

    let duration = ((Math.abs(dateIn - outDate))/3600000).toFixed(2)

    if (duration > 1) {
      var price = (duration * 2.99).toFixed(2);
    }else if (duration >= 24) {
      // change the font color to red
    }
    else{
      var price = 0;
       // change the font color to blue
      price.style.fontcolor = 'blue'    // not working
      // price.fontcolor("blue");
    }

    table.innerHTML += `<tr id=${car.id}>
                              <td>${car.license}</td>
                              <td>${price}</td>
                              <td>${duration}</td>        
                              <td>${timeIn}</td>
                              <td>${timeOut}</td>
                            </tr>`
    // table.innerHTML += row
  });

}
```

Comment: What have you tried to do 1) sorting && 2) color-setting?

Comment: @HoldOffHunger yes, but I just took the 2nd question out.

Comment: Are you working with an object that has this format to get vehicle entry and exit times? "[{
in: 1381948780803,
out: 1381986064744,
license: "FYESDQ",
}] "

Comment: @AksJacoves yes and I converted it into something like this:  5/11/2020 11:47:52 AM and now I'm trying to sort it by the exit time

Comment: What you could do is the following. Place the converted date into this object, for example:

Comment: [{
in: 1589208420000,
out: 1589208472000,
license: "FYESDQ",
date: '5/11/2020 11:47:52'}]

Comment: That way it would be easy to sort using the sort method. I will add an answer as an example

Comment: @AksJacoves thanks! I generated the day and time with new Date(car.out) then getMonth(), getDate(), getFullYear(), getHours(), getMinutes(), getSeconds(). How do I convert all these to an obj?

Comment: In fact it is not necessary, due to its converted date, it would be possible to use new Date, however, it has a date format that is incorrect in your example. You put: 5/11/2020 17: 6: 21 PM, the correct one would be 5: 6: 21 PM. With this correction I can use the sort with those converted dates as I answered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Edit**

```js
  data.sort((a, b) => b.out - a.out).forEach(car =>{
    // -------------------------------------------- Time in --------------
    let dateIn = new Date(car.in)
    let month = dateIn.getMonth()
    let date = dateIn.getDate();
    let fullYear = dateIn.getFullYear()
    let hoursIn = dateIn.getHours();
    let minutesIn = dateIn.getMinutes();
    let secondsIn = dateIn.getSeconds()

    let timeInFormat = hoursIn >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    hoursIn = hoursIn % 12

    let timeIn = month + '/' + date  + '/' + fullYear + ' ' + hoursIn + ':' + minutesIn + ':' + secondsIn + " " + timeInFormat

//input: 1591855348009
//output: 5/11/2020 16:47:48 PM

//-------------------------------------------------- Time out --------------------------------------------
    // let x = car.out
    // let carsOut = x.sort((a, b) => b - a)
    let outDate = new Date(car.out);
    // let sortedList = outDate.sort((a, b) => b.date - a.date)
    let monthOut = outDate.getMonth()
    let dateOut = outDate.getDate();
    let yearOut = outDate.getFullYear()
    let hoursOut = outDate.getHours();
    let minutesOut = outDate.getMinutes();
    let secondsOut = outDate.getSeconds()

    let timeOutFormat = hoursOut >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

    let timeOut = monthOut + '/' + dateOut  + '/' + yearOut + ' ' + hoursOut + ':' + minutesOut + ':' + secondsOut + " " + timeOutFormat

//input: 1591855348009
//output: 5/11/2020 16:47:48 PM

// ------------------------------------------ Duration

    let duration = ((Math.abs(dateIn - outDate))/3600000).toFixed(2)

    if (duration > 1) {
      var price = (duration * 2.99).toFixed(2);
    }else if (duration >= 24) {
      // change the font color to red
    }
    else{
      var price = 0;
       // change the font color to blue
      price.style.fontcolor = 'blue'    // not working
      // price.fontcolor("blue");
    }

    table.innerHTML += `<tr id=${car.id}>
                              <td>${car.license}</td>
                              <td>${price}</td>
                              <td>${duration}</td>        
                              <td>${timeIn}</td>
                              <td>${timeOut}</td>
                            </tr>`
    // table.innerHTML += row
  });

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Tried this approach....I'm working with an external API, with more than 100 objects.  "[{ in: 1381948780803, out: 1381986064744, license: "FYESDQ", }] " this's just part of the data. How do I add an object to that? Kindly, take a look at my code.

Comment: Now you are adding other subjects, but that's okay.

Comment: Use spread to add another object, like this: let data = [{value1: 'value', value2: 'value²'}], add new object: data[0] = [..data[0], value3: 'value³']

Comment: Looking at your code, something you need to do is add something below that line; let timeInFormat = hoursIn> = 12? 'PM': 'AM';

Comment: add this, hoursIn = hoursIn % 12

Comment: Looking at your code I already understood what you would need to do for this algorithm. You would have to order date before using forEach. I will edit my answer with this detail

Comment: What I did was order the date before foreach and add hoursIn = hoursIn% 12

Comment: Yessss!!!!!! It's working!!!! You're a genius. THANKS!!! @AksJacoves

Comment: Good to have helped :)

Comment: If you've time, can you also take a look at my second question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62354891/change-certain-font-color-based-calculated-hours-javascript  @AksJacoves