# Change certain font color based calculated hours - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm working on calculating parking tickets based on the time it entered and the time it exited. I am stuck on changing the color setting. So if the vehicle stays parked > 23 hr, the font color will change to 'red', and if the vehicle stays parked < 1 hr, the font color will change to 'blue'.

I tried to add comments on every step and my approach.

```
    let row = document.querySelector("#pricerow");

    if (duration > 1) {
      var price = (duration * 2.99).toFixed(2);

    } // if it's more than 23 hrs, change the font color to red
    else if (duration > 23) {
      // change the font color to red
      var price = row.style.color = "red";

    } // if the vehicle was parked for less than 1 hr, change the font color to blue
    else{
      var price = 0;
      row.style.color = "blue";
      // price.style.fontcolor = 'blue'    // not working
      // price.fontcolor("blue");
    }

    tb.innerHTML += `<tr>
                              <td>${car.license}</td>
                              <td id='pricerow'>${price}</td>
                              <td>${duration}</td>
                              <td>${timeIn}</td>
                              <td>${timeOut}</td>
                            </tr>`

  });

}
```

Comment: `price.style.fontcolor = 'blue'` does not work because `font-color` is not the CSS property, `color` is. So, you have to use `price.style.color = 'blue'` ;)

Comment: You want to change the color only if the duration is less than 1 hour or greater than 23 hours, correct?

Comment: Yes. @AksJacoves

Comment: Let's say the duration is 2 hours, that is, it is not below 1 and it is not above 23, so in that case, what color should it be? black?

Comment: There are some problems with your code that must be resolved before you can fully respond. I submitted an answer but it does not fully resolve

Comment: It will be black.

Comment: For example, you are only calculating the price if the duration exceeds 1 hour, but what if it does not? What should the price be? And in your question you want that if the duration is less than 1 the price should be in blue, but what would the price be if you did not calculate it for the case where the duration is less than 1?

Comment: If the duration is more than 1 hour then the price will be: `price = (duration * 2.99) .toFixed (2)`, but what if it is less than 1 hour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
 const table = document.querySelector(`#tableRow`)

// ------------------------------------------ Duration

    // calculating the amount of time a vehicle was parked
    let row = document.querySelector("#pricerow");
    let duration = ((Math.abs(dateIn - outDate))/3600000).toFixed(2)
    // if more than 1 hr, calculate the price
    var price = 0
    if (duration > 1) {
      price = (duration * 2.99).toFixed(2);

    } // if it's more than 23 hrs, change the font color to red
    table.innerHTML += `<tr>
                              <td>${car.license}</td>
                              <td style="color: ${(duration < 1) ? 'blue' : ((duration > 23) ? 'red' : 'black')}" id='pricerow'>${price}</td>
                              <td>${duration}</td>
                              <td>${timeIn}</td>
                              <td>${timeOut}</td>
                            </tr>`
    // table.innerHTML += row
  });

}
```

Comments:

Your code has some logic errors (which I removed in my answer) on this line for example:

```
if (duration > 1) {
  var price = (duration * 2.99).toFixed(2);

} // if it's more than 23 hrs, change the font color to red
else if (duration > 23) {
  // change the font color to red
  var price = row.style.color = "red";

} // if the vehicle was parked for less than 1 hr, change the font color to blue
else{
  var price = 0;
  row.style.color = "blue";
  // price.style.fontcolor = 'blue'    // not working
  // price.fontcolor("blue");
}
```

Note that you have, `if(duration> 1)` and `else if(duration> 23)`, the `else if(duration> 23)` will never be executed, because if duration is greater than 23 it will already be greater than 1 too, so executed only what is inside `if(duration > 1)`

Comment: Note: as you did not calculate the price in case the duration is less than 1 hour, then I put the price equal to the duration

Comment: Thanks, once again! It makes so much more sense.

Comment: I edited my answer again. I believe that when the duration was less than or equal to 1 the price should be 0, correct? My answer now considers the price to be 0 in this case

Answer (score 2):

Just set the [CSS color property](https://www.google.com/search?q=CSS%20color%20property&rlz=1C1CHBF_enCA760CA760&oq=CSS%20color%20property&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j69i60l6.2736j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) using `.style.color`.

```
var row = document.querySelector("#pricerow");
if (duration > 1) {

} // if it's more than 23 hrs, change the font color to red
else if (duration > 23) {
  // change the font color to red
  row.style.color = "red";
} // if the vehicle was parked for less than 1 hr, change the font color to blue
else{
  row.style.color = "blue";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it only changed the color of the 1st price row to 'blue' and the duration of this vehicle is > 1. Not sure what's not working here. Any idea?

Comment: @TimTim Could you please provide a reproducible example of the problem?

Comment: It's a very long piece of code, I'll try to add as much as I could.

Comment: @TimTim Try to create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem.

Comment: @TimTim Could you explain what your expected result is?

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to change the color of the 'price' text to red, if the vehicle was parked more than 23 hours (duration) and change the color of the 'price' text to blue, if it was parked for less than 1 hour (duration).                                                                                                                                            
I calculated the duration based using this formula :  let duration = ((Math.abs(dateIn - outDate))/3600000).toFixed(2)

Comment: @TimTim What is the `forEach` loop for if you only have one price tag?

Comment: For license #, time in (time the vehicle entered), time out (time the vehicle exited), total duration, price. I've 1 price tag but multiple rows. @hev1

Comment: @TimTim What exactly is `cars`? Is it an object representing one car?

Comment: no, cars represent multiple vehicles(the entire data), & 'car' represents 1 car. So,  function displayParking(data) {

  data.forEach(car =>{ })  @hev1